# How to "screenshot" a terminal with ANSI colors and export to HTML?

Tags: html, ansi

I want to do a full screen copy of some terminal output, with ANSI colors, and generate HTML so I can post to a blog or wiki.

My real world example: I want to document `top` with all of its ANSI color goodness. (I'd rather not do a bitmap screenshot. Text is more efficient.) Ideas?

Comment: See [Converting colored output into html](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/44956/20805) at our Stack Exchange sister site, [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Shouldn't this be on [superuser](http://superuser.com/)?

Comment: This probably belongs on http://unix.stackexchange.com/ -- which I just heard about today! -- as mentioned above.

Answer (score 7):

I got this idea from: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-desktop-74/preserve-colors-when-copy-pasting-from-terminal-943213/

```
sudo apt-get install aha
timestamp=$(date +%Y%m%d-%H%M%S)
top -n 1 | aha > top-$timestamp.html
```

Comment: Very nice, thanks! On RHEL/CentOS you can get the package from fedoraproject.org. For example: `sudo yum install http://download-ib01.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/Packages/a/aha-0.5-1.el7.x86_64.rpm`